# How about subtraction two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, foreach, logic

i have 2 arrays like this

```
   array1= [
          {
            "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
            "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-000000"
          },
          {
            "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
            "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-000000"
          },
          {
            "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
            "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-100000"
          }
        ]

$array2 = [
  {
    "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
    "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-000000"
  }
]
```

I want to remove the value in array1 if there is the same value in array2
so the end result I want is like this

```
$result=[
      {
        "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
        "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-000000"
      },
      {
        "SKPD_ID": "40606000",
        "SKPD_SUB1_ID": "40606000-000000760-100000"
      },
    ]
```

in the original system the array has multiple data twins, what I want is if there are twins, the resulting array will only take one data

Comment: Why doesn't it remove both copies of the value in array1?

Comment: Ok, what is your approach?

Comment: @Nick because in original data i want to delete it based on array2 not from twin data in array1

Comment: @nice_dev My constraint here is that I want to delete array1 if it has the same data as array2
but I have difficulty because the two data have no index to distinguish them

Comment: @Newbie123 Yours doesn't delete but rather just filters out the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not want to remove array 2 from array 1 but you only want to remove duplicates?

For removing duplicates from an array use  **array_unique()**
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php

This will exactly result in the desired output

```
<?

   $array1= 
       array(   
       0=>array(
        "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
        "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-000000"
      ),
      1=> array(
        "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
        "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-000000"
      ),
      2=> array(
        "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
        "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-100000"
      )
    );


echo"Original array:<br>";
print_r($array1);
          
$array2= array_unique ($array1, SORT_REGULAR);          
    
echo"<br>Array after deduplication:<br>";
  print_r($array2);
?>
```

> Output:
>
> original Array: Array (  [0] => Array (  [SKPD_ID] => 40606000
> [SKPD_SUB1_ID] => 40606000-000000760-000000 )
>
> [1] => Array (  [SKPD_ID] => 40606000  [SKPD_SUB1_ID] =>
> 40606000-000000760-000000 )
>
> [2] => Array (  [SKPD_ID] => 40606000  [SKPD_SUB1_ID] =>
> 40606000-000000760-100000 ) )
>
> ############ Array after deduplication:
>
> Array (  [0] => Array (  [SKPD_ID] => 40606000  [SKPD_SUB1_ID] =>
> 40606000-000000760-000000 )
>
> [2] => Array (  [SKPD_ID] => 40606000  [SKPD_SUB1_ID] =>
> 40606000-000000760-100000 ) )
>
> //exactly the result you desired :-)

Comment: actually what I do is delete data in array 1 if there is the same data in array2
but the problem is that there is array1 which has double data, if there is double data, then you have to look at array2 how many data is double as well.
 
it's too difficult because there's no index to tell the difference, 

but thanks for the reference, maybe i can experiment again

Comment: So i misunderstood the sentence? 
"in the original system the array has multiple data twins, what I want is if there are twins, the resulting array will only take one data"  

Perhaps you can explain what is the use of the operation.   Because there are multiple ways to get the desired results. I do not understand  your intended combination of removing the entries of array 2 in combination with the deduplication.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1= [
  [
    "SKPD_ID" => "40606000",
    "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-000000"
  ],
  [
    "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
    "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-000000"
  ],
  [
    "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
    "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-100000"
  ]
];

$array2 = [
  [
    "SKPD_ID"=> "40606000",
    "SKPD_SUB1_ID"=> "40606000-000000760-000000"
  ]
];

$found = [];
$result = [];

foreach ($array1 as $el) {
    if (in_array($el, $array2)) {
        $json = json_encode($el);
        if (!in_array($json, $found)) {
             $found[] = $json;
             $result[] = $el;
        }
    }
    else {
        $result[] = $el;
    }
}
```

You can see the result of this script [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdef780b258c76253bb96f65a8fe10a706a73507), it will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SKPD_ID] => 40606000
            [SKPD_SUB1_ID] => 40606000-000000760-000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SKPD_ID] => 40606000
            [SKPD_SUB1_ID] => 40606000-000000760-100000
        )

)
```